# Numba jit with custom numpy.dtype argument compiles only when dtype attribute is "flatten"

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Can somebody explain to me why this works:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

mytype_dtype = np.dtype([
        ('vector3', np.float32, 3),
        ('color', np.float32, 3),
        ('radius', np.float32, 1)
        ])


t = np.array([((1.,2.,3.),(0.1,0.2,0.3), 1.)], dtype=mytype_dtype)

@numba.njit
def my_func(a,b,v):
    print(v[0]['radius'])
    col = v[0]['color'].flatten()
    vec = v[0]['vector3'].flatten()
    if a>0. :
        return vec
    else:
        return col
```

And this fails:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

mytype_dtype = np.dtype([
        ('vector3', np.float32, 3),
        ('color', np.float32, 3),
        ('radius', np.float32, 1)
        ])


t = np.array([((1.,2.,3.),(0.1,0.2,0.3), 1.)], dtype=mytype_dtype)

@numba.njit
def my_func(a,b,v):
    print(v[0]['radius'])
    col = v[0]['color']
    vec = v[0]['vector3']
    if a>0. :
        return vec
    else:
        return col
```

I get an exception from Numba at compile time:

```
LoweringError: Can only insert float at [0] in [3 x float]: got i8*
```

The only difference is :

```
col = v[0]['color'].flatten()
vec = v[0]['vector3'].flatten()
```

inside **my_func**

And if I check the type are both *class 'numpy.ndarray'*

```
print(type(t[0]['color']))
print(type(t[0]['color'].flatten()))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Numpy 1.15       Numba 0.42       Python 3.7.1

Comment: The error message is saying that it's getting a `np.int32` where it expects a `np.float32`, double check your dtypes. Probably it would help to include a function signature in the `njit` statement, to make explicit what dtype `b` is supposed to be.